# Using variables within codeception tests

Tags: codeception

How do we use string replacements and variables in the tests? I suspect this is common and I simply do not know where to look. Example test:

```
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Get Stuff');
$I->amHttpAuthenticated('myuser', 'mypass');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Custom-Header', 'friendlycorp');
$I->sendGet('/a/path/that/contains/variables');
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK);
```

Each REST API location being tested uses different values, and also the URL changes depending on the service being tested. So, perhaps something like:

```
$I->amHttpAuthenticated('{USERNAME}', '{PASSWORD}');
$I->sendGet('/a/path/{SERVICE_ID}/and/{SOMETHING_ELSE}/and/such');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Custom-Header', '{SERVICE_ID}');
```

I'm hopeful that a configuration file could then define the likes of {SERVICE_ID} and {FUNCTION} depending on the REST API service location I'm testing, along with other variables. For example:

```
FriendlyCorp:
    SERVICE_ID: friendlycorp
    SOMETHING_ELSE: foo
    USERNAME: myuser
    PASSWORD: mypass
OpenExample:
    SERVICE_ID: openexample
    SOMETHING_ELSE: bar
    USERNAME: myuser2
    PASSWORD: mypass2
```

Then when executing codeception I'd choose to run tests against FriendlyCorp or OpenExample and said values would be used within the tests.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Cest](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Cest-Classes) format with [Examples](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Examples)

```
 /**
  * @example { "service_id": "friendlycorp", "something_else": "foo", "username": "myuser", "password": "mypass" }
  * @example { "service_id": "openexample", "something_else": "bar", "username": "myuser2", "password": "mypass2" }
  */
  public function services(ApiTester $I, \Codeception\Example $example)
  {
    $I->amHttpAuthenticated($example['username'], $example['username']);
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Custom-Header', $example['service_id']);
    $I->sendGet("/a/path/{$example['service_id']}/and/{$example['something_else']}/and/such");
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK);
  }
```